# Taking in user input from a different thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, sfml

I'm making a timer program the counts the time passed since the program started. In the background I'm also checking for keyboard input (enter/return to exit, click on the window); this is done in a separate thread I've run as *detached*.

It seems the second thread cannot receive the input from the main thread. When I use the keyboard or mouse, nothing happens. Also, nothing appears on the screen, just white.

```
std::mutex g_mutex;
std::condition_variable cv;

// check for input from the user using the window object
// sets stopProgram to true if the user wishes to exit
void poll(sf::RenderWindow& window, bool& stopProgram) {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(g_mutex);
    // wait for main thread to open window
    cv.wait(lk, [&] { return !stopProgram && window.isOpen(); });
    sf::Event event;
    while (true) {
        if (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            // if user wants to exit program
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed || (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed &&
                (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Return || event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape))) {
                window.close();
                // main thread will explicitly exit the main loop
                stopProgram = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int hour = 0, minute = 0, second = 0;
    auto text = textObject();
    bool stopProgram = false;
    // run a background thread that checks for input while the main program runs
    std::thread(poll, std::ref(window), std::ref(stopProgram)).detach();
    std::once_flag flag;

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(g_mutex);
    while (window.isOpen()) {
        // notify once window opens
        std::call_once(flag, [&] { cv.notify_one(); });
        // set timestamp
        text->setString(makeTimeStamp(hour, minute, second));
        // if the background thread set stopProgram, end the program
        if (stopProgram) break;
        window.clear(sf::Color::White);
        window.draw(*text);
        window.display();
        // update time
        second = (second + 1) % MAX_SEC;
        if (second == 0) minute = (minute + 1) % MAX_MIN;
        if (second == 0 && minute == 0) hour = (hour + 1) % MAX_HOUR;
        // sleep one second
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}
```

Is my use of multithreading correct? If so, can only the main thread receive input and that's why it's not working?

Update: If I get rid of the `while (true)` and use `while (window.pollEvent(event))` and move the `lock_guard` to just before `if (stopProgram)` then the text (timestamp) appears on the screen, but I still cannot process input.

Comment: calling `std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1)); ` doesn't necessarily means that your program will resume in 1 second. So, if you want an accurate counting check the difference between the current time and the previous.

Comment: Also, `unique_lock` is used only with shared mutexes. using unique_lock on non-shared mutex is basically calling `lock_guard`. You should read about shared mutexes on http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex

Comment: @TalShalti How do I check if the difference in time is exactly one second?

Comment: Sleeping for 1s only guarantee you'll sleep at least 1 second. To calculate difference in time, use the function `std::chrono::system_clock::now()` before and after the thing you want to calculate the time for, and then substract one value from the other

Comment: cant you just use global values and or a function? You can access the same functions and global variables, regardless of the thread

Comment: @TalShalti When I subtract the values I do `if (now - prev == std::chrono::seconds(1))` to see if it was one second, but it doesn't work for me

Comment: @TalShalti Never mind I got it to work. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

main thread launches poll thread.

```
std::thread(poll, std::ref(window), std::ref(stopProgram)).detach();
```

main thread acquires g_mutex and *never ever releases it*.

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(g_mutex);
```

poll thread waits for g_mutex to be released:

```
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(g_mutex);
```

but the main thread *never releases it*, so the poll thread never does anything.

To fix it.  Change the beginning of the main() function:

```
int main()
{
    int hour = 0, minute = 0, second = 0;
    auto text = textObject();
    volatile bool stopProgram = false;
    // run a background thread that checks for input while the main program runs
    std::thread(poll, std::ref(window), std::ref(stopProgram)).detach();

    while (!window.isOpen()) { /* busy loop */ }
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lk(g_mutex);
        cv.notify_all();
    }
    while (window.isOpen()) {
       ...
```

This SFML API makes things more difficult than other windowing frameworks that I've used.  It would be sooo useful if there were a thread-safe  window.pushCustomEvent() function.

Comment: What goes inside `/* busy loop */` and why is `stopProgram` now `volatile`?

Comment: Nothing goes in /*busy loop*/.  The comment tells the reader that I didn't accidentally write a while loop with nothing in it.  I intended to write a while loop with nothing in it.